# How speed up mysql dump without data?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

There are a lot of questions ([1](https://serverfault.com/questions/146525/how-can-i-speed-up-a-mysql-restore-from-a-dump-file),[2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46889/how-to-speed-up-a-mysql-restore-from-large-dump-file),[3](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94149/how-to-speed-up-mysql-export-and-import)) about speed up MySql restoring. But all of them speed up **data** import. Is there a way to speed up schema tables creation? For example dump iundepended table in parallel and restoring them in parallel too.

Btw, `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` is not a solution, becase standart mysql dump creates dump file with that statement.

Comment: Which version you are using in MySQL 5.7 you have mysqlpump and you can have multiple threads of dump to speed that up.

Comment: I use MySql 5.6

Answer (score 0):

File creation is the main part of the sluggishness, especially on Windows.  So, decreasing the number of *files* is key to speeding up your process.

Each MyISAM table needs 3 files.  Each InnoDB table needs 1 or 2 files.  Switch to InnoDB if not already using it.

Each `PARTITION` is a "table", so it counts as above.  More than about 50 partitions is inefficient, and this is one of the reasons.

Having more than a thousand tables is usually (not always) a sign of a poorly designed schema.

`VIEWs`, `TRIGGERs`, Stored routines, etc each take at least one file.

Parallel loading may or may not help; it depends on whether the OS can create multiple files in parallel.